# Hiding point by index in three.js THREE.Points object

Tags: javascript, three.js, visibility, point

I have got the following issue with an object containing many points (created with `THREE.Points`). An example would be `https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_interactive_points`. Now, I am trying to hide a specific point if I click on it. Using the ´intersect`-method I'm able to enlarge these or change their color: using` particles.geometry.attributes.size.array[INDEX]`and setting`.needsUpdate`. However, I complete invisibility is not possible. The goal is to hide the points by the INDEX it has in the 'buffer geometry'. Below you can find a code snippet of the example.

```
var vertices = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 16, 16, 16 ).vertices;

var positions = new Float32Array( vertices.length * 3 );
var colors = new Float32Array( vertices.length * 3 );
var sizes = new Float32Array( vertices.length );

var vertex;
var color = new THREE.Color();

for ( var i = 0, l = vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    vertex = vertices[ i ];
    vertex.toArray( positions, i * 3 );

    color.setHSL( 0.01 + 0.1 * ( i / l ), 1.0, 0.5 );
    color.toArray( colors, i * 3 );

    sizes[ i ] = PARTICLE_SIZE * 0.5;

}

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
geometry.setAttribute( 'customColor', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
geometry.setAttribute( 'size', new THREE.BufferAttribute( sizes, 1 ) );

//

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: {
        color: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
        pointTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/sprites/disc.png" ) }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,

    alphaTest: 0.9

} );

//

particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
scene.add( particles );
```

Changing the 'size' on hover works as the following:

```
// function render() {

particles.rotation.x += 0.0005;
particles.rotation.y += 0.001;

var geometry = particles.geometry;
var attributes = geometry.attributes;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( particles );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].index ) {

        attributes.size.array[ INTERSECTED ] = PARTICLE_SIZE;

        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].index;

        attributes.size.array[ INTERSECTED ] = PARTICLE_SIZE * 1.25;
        attributes.size.needsUpdate = true;

    }
```

I have looked at shaders (in my opinion way too complex for this task) and trying to create transparent material. Is there something overlooked?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you just the clicked point's alpha color to 0?

Comment: @Mikepote It involves the using of `transparent: true` for `PointsMaterial` and it leads to undesired/unpredictable results: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/shader-to-create-an-offset-inward-growing-stroke/6060/20?u=prisoner849

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an option, using of an additional buffer attribute for visibility and processing it in shaders, does the trick:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x444444);
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let g = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10);
g.index = null;
let pos = g.getAttribute("position");
let colors = [];
let color = new THREE.Color();
let sizes = [];
let visibility = [];
for(let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
  color.set( Math.random() * 0x888888 + 0x888888);
  colors.push(color.r, color.g, color.b);
  sizes.push( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.5);
  visibility.push(1);
}
g.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
g.setAttribute("sizes", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(sizes, 1));
g.setAttribute("visibility", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(visibility, 1));

let m = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  vertexColors: true,
  onBeforeCompile: function(shader){
    shader.vertexShader = `
      attribute float sizes;
      attribute float visibility;
      varying float vVisible;
    ${shader.vertexShader}`
    .replace(
      `gl_PointSize = size;`,
      `gl_PointSize = size * sizes;
        vVisible = visibility;
      `
    );
    shader.fragmentShader = `
      varying float vVisible;
    ${shader.fragmentShader}`
    .replace(
      `#include <clipping_planes_fragment>`,
      `
        if (vVisible < 0.5) discard;
      #include <clipping_planes_fragment>`
    )
  }
});

let p = new THREE.Points(g, m);
scene.add(p);

let oldIndex = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  let newIndex = THREE.Math.randInt(0, pos.count - 1);
  g.attributes.visibility.setX(oldIndex, 1);
  g.attributes.visibility.setX(newIndex, 0);
  oldIndex = newIndex;
  g.attributes.visibility.needsUpdate = true;
}, 500);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
function animate(){
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

</script>
```